# Long text is starting from the bottom in \tcolorbox

Tags: vertical-alignment, tcolorbox, white-space

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,openright,12pt]{book} 

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[listings,skins,breakable,hooks]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[color]{changebar}

\newcommand\A{True choice is \textbf{A}.}

\newcommand{\dort}[4]{
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\Alph*}),itemsep=-3pt,topsep=1pt]
\item #1
    \item #2
        \item #3
            \item #4
\end{enumerate}}

\definecolor{formulzemin}{RGB}{255,255,170}

\newcommand*\mybox[1]{%
\colorbox{formulzemin}{\hspace{1em}#1\hspace{1em}}}

\newcommand{\denk}[1]{\begin{empheq}[box=\mybox]{align}{\textnormal{#1}\nonumber}\end{empheq}}

\newcommand{\kutu}[2]{\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced jigsaw,breakable, left=0mm,right=0mm,bottom=0mm,top=0mm,colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,pad at break=1mm,]#1 \begin{flushright}\textit{#2}\end{flushright}\end{tcolorbox}}

\newcommand{\soru}[1]{\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,breakable=false,left=0mm,right=0mm,bottom=0mm,top=0mm,colback=white!5!white,colframe=white!75!white,frame hidden,borderline={.3mm}{0mm}{blue,dotted}]{#1}\end{tcolorbox}}

\begin{document}
\newgeometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,marginparwidth=0cm,marginparsep=0cm,outer=1cm}
\twocolumn

\begin{enumerate}

\soru{\item Question one?
\dort{ITU}{ECC}{HAM}{ARRL}}
\kutu{\denk{International Telecommunication Union}}{\A}
\kutu{\denk{International Union}}{\A}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

And output

[image]

If the answer choice is long, there is whitespace on it. If answer choice is short, there is no whitespace on it. Beginning of long answer choice start place of short answer. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need to add the option keys in tcolorbox of `\kutu` command:

- `oversize`: to prevent the size of tcb to be proportional to the length of text and,
- `halign=center`: to center the text of tcb horizontally.

[image]

```
\newcommand{\kutu}[2]{%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[%
        oversize,
        halign=center,
        enhanced jigsaw,
        breakable, left=0mm,
        right=0mm,bottom=0mm,top=0mm,
        colback=red!5!white,
        colframe=red!75!black,
        pad at break=1mm]
        #1%
        \begin{flushright}
            \textit{#2}
        \end{flushright}
    \end{tcolorbox}
}
```

**UPDATE**

If minor possible space between text and top border of tcolorbox is wanted, one can add declaration `\abovedisplayskip=0pt` right after the beginning of the `\kutu` environment.
Also spaces from text to borders has been changed to: `left = -1mm, right = -1mm`.

```
\soru{%
    \item Question one?
    \dort{ITU}{ECC}{HAM}{ARRL}
}

\kutu{%
\abovedisplayskip=0pt
\denk{International Telecommunication Union}}{\A}
\kutu{%
\abovedisplayskip=0pt
\denk{International Union}}{\A}
```

[image]

Comment: What should it be to start a little above `halign=`, as in the second red box in the problem?